# How to improve font of a TextButton on Android

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, textview, scaling

I have some squarish TextViews (with different dynamic sizes(I don't know them while I'm developing)) in my Application and want to set their text. But if I say TextView.setText(); the text font is pretty small. If I set TextView.setFontSize sometimes the text is not fully displayed (remember: they have a dynamic size). So my question: how can I give the text the perfect font (using the full space of the button AND being fully displayed) or make the Text squarish itself so that it fills the whole space of the TextView?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Paint.getTextBounds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29) like this:

```
int textViewWidth = textView.getMeasuredWidth();
float textSize = 1.0;
do {
    textSize += 0.5
    textView.setTextSize(textSize);
    Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), rect);
    int width = rect.width();
} while (width < textViewWidth);

textView.setTextSize(textSize - 0.5);
```

Comment: // increment this value in a loop until it just fits the textview's bounds - How should I know that in my programm? (I can't do it static (textview sizes are dynamic))

Comment: It would help  me if you could tell me how to change the "text rectangle" of a TextView. (Scale the text so that it has the width...and the height...)

Comment: Now that you have the text height that gets larger or smaller to fit the textview(by incrementing or decrementing text size), don't you know how to compare text height with height of the TextView?

Comment: Thank you - I didn't understand you the first time

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextScaleX%28float%29), it looks like you should be able to use something like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
tv.setTextScaleX(tv.getWidth());
```

This will scale the width of your text to the width of the `TextView`.

Comment: This doesn't work. I already tried it. The text looks pretty strange then. (I can't upload a pic :-()

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to calculate heights of the button and the text you wish to set. APIs you will need are: [Paint.getTextBounds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29) and View.getHeight().

Comment: I already calculated the height of the TextViews (I don't have buttons). The problem is that the text of the TextView doesn't fill the hole TextView. That's why I'm writing...